# How to share local host's files with docker machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-machine, traefik

I am fairly new to docker, i have been having issues for days now setting up docker-machine to share local files on my windows pc through the use of volumes.

Basically, i am using the github repo as staerting point https://github.com/koutsoumposval/laravel-microservices. I noticed that when i do not use docker-machine the files are shared using the 'volumes' configuration in my docker-compose file.

However, when i host the same project on the docker machine the files do not show. i can see the top level folders when i ssh into the docker machine but they are all empty.

Also i was able to get the local files to show up in the docker-machine by using the 'COPY' directive in the Dockerfile. but i am not comfortable with this, as changes made to the local files are not automatically reflected in the docker machine.

So my question is how can i synchronize the local files with the docker-machine since the 'volumes' directory is obviously not working. Also please point me in the right direction if i am thinking about this in the wrong way.

DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
 version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=lm.local --docker.exposedbydefault=false --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml

  order:
    build:
      context: order/php-apache
    volumes:
      - ../order:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:order.lm.local"
      - "traefik.backend=order"
    networks:
      - webgateway
      - web
    restart: always

  user:
    build:
      context: user/php-apache
    volumes:
      - ../user:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:user.lm.local"
      - "traefik.backend=user"
    networks:
      - webgateway
      - web
    restart: always

  inventory:
    build:
      context: inventory/php-apache
    volumes:
      - ../inventory:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:inventory.lm.local"
      - "traefik.backend=inventory"
    networks:
      - webgateway
      - web
    restart: always

  api:
    build:
      context: api-gateway/php-apache
    volumes:
      - ../api-gateway:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.lm.local"
      - "traefik.backend=api"
    networks:
      - webgateway
      - web
    restart: always

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

The image below shows the errors i am experiencing as a result of the local files not being copied to the the virtual machine. So the 'html' folder which is suppose to contain the full microservice repo is empty.
  [image: Error message when i run docker-compose]

Comment: Care must be observed with Docker context. I suspect this is what's impacting you here with your use of sibling directories (`../[sibling]) for the volume mappings. I recommend anchoring your Docker context in the parent directory (`..`), running docker-compose from there and making references from that point.

Comment: Unrelated to the above but it's curious to map `traefik.toml` onto the host's `/dev/null`. I'm unable to understand how this could function.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you so much for your response, I think the issue has to do with docker-machine on windows (i'm using windows :( ). Because just running docker-compose alone on my localhost, everything works fine and the volumes are sharing the local files with the containers

Comment: @DazWilkin I am thinking of using kubernetes, but i have very little experience with it.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're using different hosts (Windows and what you refer to as docker-machine), you will need to ensure that both hosts have files in the same locations to share into the containers when the images are run. I'm a proponent of Kubernetes (and recommended hosted services like Kubernetes Engine) but please ensure you'd benefit from the platform before adoption it (there's complexity too).